# Batch file for loop, destination doesn't update

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a loop to transfer files and rename the destination path, this is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (
list of files
) do (
set DST=%%%X:20180101=!.!%
@echo Copying...
@echo  From: %%X
@echo    To: %DST%
REM COPY %%X !DST! /V /Y
)
```

The problem is that the destination isn't changing it stays as the first path and file in the loop, how can I ensure its correct?

The intention in the above loop is to replace path of the path with . which works but the path isn't changing with the source.

Comment: you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @npocmaka, see line 2 isn't that what I have?

Comment: do you just want to add a dot instead of the date?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, no, I put in the . to deal with the \\, I want to remove the 20180101 and end up with \.\ instead of \\

Comment: but that is not hapening anywhere here, you are simply trying files, not path to files.?

Comment: but then what you are trying to achieve on this line `set DST=%%%X:20180101=!.!%` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, an sample file looks like this:  C:\SomeFolder\20180101\MoreSubFolders\fileName.ext, what I want to do is end up with removing 20180101\

Comment: @npocmaka, to remove 20180101 and replace with . so in the case of  C:\SomeFolder\20180101\MoreSubFolders\fileName the replacement would look like  C:\SomeFolder\.\MoreSubFolders\fileName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming something like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  set dst=%%~fi
  set dst=!dst:20180101=.!
  echo !dst!
  @echo Copying...
  @echo  From: %%~fi
  @echo    To: !DST!
  REM COPY %%~fi !DST! /V /Y
)
```

Note how we use delayedexpansion with the `!` instead of `%`

for more on delayedexpansion, see `set /?` and `setlocal /?`